# Keep a Session alive after PayPal payment

Tags: php, mysql, session

I create PHP session for storing the user email in 'submit.php' where before redirecting to paypal I register that user information into a database using MySQL. This is the code for creating the session in 'submit.php':

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user-email']=$email;
```

So now the user pays at PayPal successfully and goes to 'thankyou.php' and I want to update my database saying the user paid and calling the PHP session:

```
session_start();
    $email = $_SESSION['user-email'];
    $con = mysql_connect("host.host.com","root","password");
    if (!$con) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
    mysql_select_db("somedatabase", $con);

    $sql="UPDATE myTable SET status=1 WHERE email='$email'";
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con)) { die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); }
    mysql_close($con);
```

Is the $_SESSION['user-email']; still alive at this point? Do I have any error? Why do you think my code is not working properly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you describe what happens when your second script runs?

Comment: You should read about mysqli! http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: Hello Sam, my second script actually receives de Paypal IPN and if the Payment was successful or not. If it is successful I should update the database for status=1 means the user paid, the default is status=0 meaning the user hasn't paid.